# Problem with while-end loop

Tags: matlab

This is a peice of code written in Matlab:

```
while flag==1
    flag = 0;
    disp('end of loop');
end
```

Surprisingly, this does not display the string. If I remove the `disp` statement a figure1 window appears. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Since this question is more about programming than computational science, I would suggest moving it to stack overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is simply because `flag` is a defined command in matlab. Try typing `flag` just after having started Matlab and you will see a non-empty matrix appearing. If you type `help flag` you will see the meaning of that function.

Also, the function is selected by Matlab because you do not declare a variable called `flag` before your code. If you write `flag=1` before your code, it works as expected.

Still, the best way is to change the name of your variable in order not to hide the Matlab function. So, use the following code:

```
myflag = 1;
while( myflag == 1)
    myflag = 0;
    disp('end of loop');
end
```